# Python BeautifulSoup: equivalent to a browser node.innerText

Tags: javascript, python, html, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

Ive been trying to extract some data from a crawled site using pythons beautifulsoup library. I found out that searching for a node and using .text on it to get its content does work but somehow messes up formatting and the string doesnt end up being formatted as it is on a webpage. I found out that there is a way of using .innerText in a browser which returns a string of some html text as if a user would copy paste it. Is there an equivalent for that in python or do I actually need to run it in a browser?

Comment: Can you share the URL and expected output? Also a code what have you tried so far...

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with beautifulsoup, you just use this `.text` like this behind your soup object

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

r = requests.get("https://YourUrl.com")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
result = soup.find_all('body') # this will give you everything in body, 
# if you want anything else, you can specify by adding a dictionary into the parameters
```

Comment: that does actually not work because some text nodes contain whitespaces/newlines/tabs which are not rendered in an actual browser.